# rewrite name for it to work - keep it real name

Tags: c#, asp.net

such that I have hidde on my side but the reshaping name by hidden, I would like to keep it in your name and not add anything more,

problem is that I would like to just have the name has only protocol and should not add it over to this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$protocol" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_protocol" value="7" />
```

it must come to be like this and no I can not just use html only,

```
<input type="hidden" name="protocol" id="protocol" value="7" />
```

**here the code that I use for the page.**

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="protocol" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="msgtype" runat="server"  />
<asp:HiddenField ID="merchant" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="language" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="ordernumber" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="amount" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="currency" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="continueurl" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="cancelurl" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="callbackurl" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="autocapture" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="md5check" runat="server" />
```

This is how I printed it on this page, which value value

```
string protocol_value = "7";
            string msgtype_value = "authorize";
            string language_value = "da";
            string autocapture_value = "0";
            string ordernum_value = Session["orderId"].ToString();
            string merchant_value = "89898978";
            string amount_value = readerPriser["priser"].ToString();
            string qp_currency_value = "DKK";
            string okpage_value = "../handelsbetingelserContinue.aspx";
            string errorPage_value = "../handelsbetingelserCallback.aspx";
            string resultpage_value = "../handelsbetingelserError.aspx";
            string md5secret_value = "29p61DveBZ79c3144LW61lVz1qrwk2gfAFCxPyi5sn49m3Y3IRK5M6SN5d8a68u7";
            string md5check_value = GenerateHash(string.Concat(protocol_value.ToString(), msgtype_value, merchant_value, language_value, ordernum_value, amount_value.ToString(), qp_currency_value, okpage_value, errorPage_value, resultpage_value,
            autocapture_value.ToString(), md5secret_value));

            protocol.Value = protocol_value;
            msgtype.Value = msgtype_value;
            language.Value = language_value;
            autocapture.Value = autocapture_value;
            ordernumber.Value = ordernum_value;
            merchant.Value = merchant_value;
            amount.Value = amount_value;
            currency.Value = qp_currency_value;
            continueurl.Value = okpage_value;
            cancelurl.Value = errorPage_value;
            callbackurl.Value = resultpage_value;
            md5check.Value = md5check_value;
```

Comment: What if you specify the attribute ? `<asp:HiddenField ID="protocol" name="protocol" runat="server" />``

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="protocol" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

ASP.NET provides four modes of generating client IDs:

- AutoID
- Static
- Predictable
- Inherit

Here you may find details:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: i try to its here: `LiteralProtocol.Text = "<input id=\"protocol\" name=\"protocol\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"" + protocol_value + '" />';`

Comment: Landeeyo's answer is the correct one. But if you create html elements in literals don't expect .NET to go get the values back out of them. Are you trying to get these values out of the Hidden fields using JavaScript?